# Need to edit django get request to include list of models given a list of id's

Tags: python, sql, django, model, backend

I'm currently creating the backend for a website in which users can add public events/gatherings to their favorites list. I'm currently creating a model in Django which models a user created account named Account. I want to implement it so that Account includes a field called "favorites" which stores the id's of the Events that the specific account added to their favorites.

Answer (score 0):

Before answering the question, I would like to talk about the models. First, a good practice is to [extend](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model) or [substitute](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model) an User model. And, secondly a [many-to-many](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/#many-to-many-relationships) relationship would be more adequate (one user has many favorite events, and one event is favorited by many users).

An example substituting the model, using an app named `core`:

settings.py

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'core.Account'
```

models.py

```
class Account(AbstractUser):
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    favorites = models.ManyToManyField('Event')

class Event(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(null=True) # will have to figure out where this image is uploaded to
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
    date = models.DateTimeField(max_length=50, null=True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
    description = models.TextField(null=True)
```

Now, related to the question. The implementation method will depend on the kind of `service`, if it is either a plain web service or an API.

For instance, for a plain `web service` you can build the response yourself using Python lists and dictionaries, in this case a list containing all users with their favorite events:

views.py

```
from django.forms.models import model_to_dict
from .models import Event, Account

def favorites(request):
    data = []
    accounts = Account.objects.all()
    for account in accounts:
        obj = model_to_dict(account, fields=('username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'phone_number'))
        obj['favorites'] = []
        for favorite in account.favorites.all():
            obj['favorites'].append(model_to_dict(favorite, fields=('id', 'name', 'data', 'location', 'description')))

        data.append(obj)

    return HttpResponse(data)
```

On the other hand, if it is an API service and you are using [DRF](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/), then it would be something similar to:

serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from .models import Event

class EventSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Event
        fields = ['id', 'image', 'name', 'date', 'location', 'description']

class AccountSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    favorites = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()
        fields = ['username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'phone_number', 'favorites']

    def get_favorites(self, obj):
        return EventSerializer(obj.favorites.all(), many=True).data
```

views.py

```
from rest_framework import generics
from .serializers import AccountSerializer
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

class UserListAPIView(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = get_user_model().objects.all()
    serializer_class = AccountSerializer
```

Obs.: I only implemented `GET` requests for both scenarios. You would still have to write `POST` (for plain service) or have a [ListCreateAPIView](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#listcreateapiview) and attach an event to an account e.g. `account.favorites.add(event)`

Answer (score 0):

That favorites table is supposed to be a many to many relationship table especially that you have no additional fields, but what you have done is only link it to the account model, and I m a little bit confused by that favorite field which is just a positive integer? what you should have done instead is

```
class Account(models.Model):
   username = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True)
   .....
   favorites = models.ManyToManyField(Event)
```

this way if you have an account object you can access its favorite events just like this

```
// create an account
account = new Account(username='foo', firstname....)
account.save()

// create an event 
event = new Event(event_name='bar',...)
event.save()

// add an event to an account's favorite events list
account.favorites.add(event)

// access an account's favorite events
account.favorites.all()
```

You should also be consistent with naming your models and always use singular nouns